# How do I autostart Jenkins agent machines?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, virtualization, google-compute-engine

To save money, I would like a large number of agent machines to be stopped and started up only when needed. Better yet, a single  VM should be copied and launched on demand.

I am using Google Cloud Platform.

I see the  [Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes), used in Jenkins X, as well as the  [VirtualBox Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/VirtualBox+Plugin), but I get the sense that Jenkins might not be designed for this.

What is the standard way, if any, to do this?

Comment: `but I get the sense that Jenkins might not be designed for this`. Please explain why.

Comment: Because I find very little info on the Web about how to do it. If autostart  were a standard approach, the documents about setting up the agent would include it as a basic case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050127/is-possible-for-jenkins-to-auto-start-and-stop-slave-nodes

Comment: Thank you. From the discussions online, it seems that  the most usual way to use Jenkins is to keep a constant number of slave VMs running.

Comment: Perhaps Jenkins x provides a solution, but I have not tried. I hope that start with that the upcoming days. Did you already deploy Jenkins x?

Comment: I have not tried Jenkins X.

Comment: Also, this describes how to create ephemeral; agents  in GCE https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine

Answer (score 1):

We use AWS's [EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) to spin up spot instances in AWS for our Jenkins master based on a single AMI, exactly as you describe, so Jenkins does support this behavior.

From a quick bit of searching Google Cloud seems to offer [a similar solution](http://blog.spotinst.com/2016/08/31/elastigroup-jenkins-plugin-google-cloud-platform/);

> Spotinst’s Jenkins Plugin helps you to do more with your Jenkins setup by allowing you to automatically configure and scale a designated Google Compute Engine Preemptible VM as Slaves up and down depending on the number jobs to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Google just announced this [Jenkins plugin for GCE](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-compute-engine) , which does support autoscaling.